# The db2prereqcheck utility was unable to determine the Linux distribution level

Tags: linux, db2, ibm-cloud, linux-mint, db2-400

I am working on Linux Mint and when I tried installing IBM DB2 following the steps in below link, 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0008875.html

I got this error in the step when I check installation requirements

```
DBT3505E  The db2prereqcheck utility was unable to determine the Linux distribution level.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint is not a supported operating system for Db2.

If you dig hard enough, starting with this document, you can determine the supported operating systems:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system-requirements-ibm-db2-linux-unix-and-windows

For Db2 v11.5, the supported Linux operating systems are RHEL7.5, SLES12SP3, or Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 is "not supported" on Linux Mint. What does that mean?

It means that the paid defect-support channel for Db2  will likely reject requests for help for Db2 on Linux Mint. They will ask you to first recreate the symptom on a supported distribution.  That allows them to investigate on a supported distro.

But 'not supported' does **not** mean that Db2 will not work. Instead, you might need to do additional pre-requsites installation or configuration work, or other troubleshooting activities to solve issues.

For example, Db2 is *not supported* by the IBM paid defect support when Db2 runs on **Centos** or **Fedora** distributions. But Db2 runs happily on these distributions **as long as you know what you are doing** , and always install from the latest-fixpack-server-build image of Db2 (but never the GA build).

So 'not supported' means that when it goes wrong, it's up to you to find a solution and the paid channel for Db2-defect-support won't help you.

Most companies value their data and want some kind of support so most companies will use a supported distribution. But if you are in a non-production or development environment, and if you have the time and competence and patience to do troubleshooting then you can make progress and learn stuff.

As regards the specific, symptom **DBT3505E** , there is already an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984454/db2-db2prereqcheck-how-to-make-it-work) , always search for the symptom-code first on stackoverflow!